# Changing orientation of Xamarin iOS app does not show pop up in the center of the screen on screen rotation

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xctool

I am using Xamarin tool kit pop up in my Xamarin app iOS. It works fine in portrait mode. If I change the orientation to landscape mode while the pop up is already opened, the pop up does not show in the center of the screen. It shows on the left corner of the screen. It works well in android but in iOS it shows on left corner on screen rotation.

Below is my pop up code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xct:Popup xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:xct="clr-namespace:Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views;assembly=Xamarin.CommunityToolkit"
           Size="360,200"
           IsLightDismissEnabled="False"
           x:Class="Mobile.NewPopup">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
        <Label Text="Sample PopUp"/>
    </StackLayout>
</xct:Popup>
```

I am calling like this from the button click of my page.

```
await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ShowPopupAsync(new NewPopup();
```

In portrait mode it is opening in the center of the screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fwS9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TPBD.png)

How can I move this the pop up to the center of the screen while in landscape mode?

Comment: Please be noted that this is a known issue for `iOS` and there's an open thread: [Bug iOS Popup: Position of Popup is not centered when the orientation of the device changes #1396](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/1396), you can follow up there.

Answer (score 0):

When opening your popup subscribe to the **Application.Current.MainPage.SizeChanged** event to get notified when the screen rotates between *Portrait* and *Landscape*.

And then manually fire the **PropertyChanged** event for the **VerticalOptions** or **HorizontalOptions** property of the popup via **OnPropertyChanged**. This will force the PopupRenderer to recenter the popup.

```
//constructor of popup
public NewPopup()
{
   Application.Current.MainPage.SizeChanged += MainPage_SizeChanged
}

private void MainPage_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(VerticalOptions));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Core.HandleError(ex);
    }
}
```